# How can I fix my cheap Android 2.2 phone? Should I root it?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, performance, samsung-intercept

I recently purchased a [Samsung Intercept](http://www.virginmobileusa.com/cell-phones/samsung-intercept-phone.jsp) for Virgin Mobile. The problem is that it doesn't work very well. There's a delay when doing almost anything on it, even calling or texting. It also has poor battery life. Is there a way I can get it to work decently? Perhaps by removing apps? Would rooting it get it to work better?

Answer (score 1):

IF you know what you're doing, rooting and flashing a custom rom CAN help. Rooting it will allow you to delete some "system" apps that you don't need, and give you access to more control over your CPU, and some ROMs have ways to help save battery. My sister was forced to get a Droid 2 Global after two faulty replacements of her original Droid 1 which she loved, and she hated the Global. Had problems with battery and the way it was set up and everything. So I rooted it for her and flashed a new rom, and she got an extended battery (VERY USEFUL SUGGESTION), and now she loves it. But as rooting voids your warranty, I wouldn't try it if you don't need to or don't know exactly what you're doing.